# How can I add a parameter to the Tapped event of a ViewCell?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

Here is the code I have:

```
<ViewCell x:Name="noa" Tapped="pickerTapped()">
```

I would like to send a string parameter to the pickerTapped() method.  How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know if this is the right way, but you can go by Command.
First define MyCommand and then call it in your pickerTapped event.

```
void pickerTapped (object sender, System.EventArgs e) 
{
    if (MyCommand != null && MyCommand.CanExecute(null)) {
        MyCommand.Execute(null);
    }
};
```